# Select top N columns based on standardized values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

[image]Got a bit of googly question. Is it possible to select say  10 columns based on the values in each column if all the values are standardized.

So for example

```
cluster Id | v1 | v2| v3 | v4 | v6 | v26 
___________________________________________
       1   | 4.2|0.9|05  |3.2 | 0.7|0.5
       2   | 1.2|0.1|0.9 |0.21|0.3 |0.1
```

so in this example if I wanted 3 top three columns for cluster 1  i'd have

```
     cluster ID |v1 |v4 |v2
            1   |4.2|3.2|0.9
```

I'm open to any suggestions at the moment i'm using Oracle Sql but wiling to switch if theres a solution on a different platform and its impossible using SQL

edit. I've added an image which shows the feature i'm trying to replicate on Sql developer. The fetch size is the number of variables/attributes and there must be some table sitting behind the model that's being queried when I change the fetch size and thats the statement i'm trying to reproduce
thank you

Comment: Top 3? You mean 1st 3 columns or top 3 rows (Assuming former)?

Also, what problem are you trying to solve exactly? You might be thinking of this wrong (Like using parameters / Entities)

Comment: "All the values are *standardized*"? What does that mean? Then: what is the desired format of the output? A result set in four columns? Do you need to "remember" that the top values came from columns v1, v4, v2? (You have a typo, too: the value 4.2 is from v1, not v2). The whole project is quite nebulous, regardless of language/platform.

Comment: Austin French - Top three columns and the idea is to pull the variables with the highest means. I've used ODM and K means clustering to create a model and I can view the data I want using the model viewer on Sql and change the settings to get the top 10 , 20 etc variables for each cluster. However I cant recreate the query as a select statment its all menu driven.

Comment: @mathguy . . . "standardization" is a statistical term where you subtract the average and divide by the standard deviation. It removes the units from a columns and puts all columns in a compatible range.  It is quite useful for a range of statistical techniques.

Comment: 1)  Are there always `6` value columns?  2) Will you always be selecting the same number of highest values?  3) You can't rename columns, so would you prefer `cluster_id, 1st_col_num, 1st_col_val, 2nd_col_num, 2nd_col_val, etc, etc` *(highest value is always in the `1st_` pair of columns, and the `col_num` tells you which column the `col_val` came from)*, or would you prefer to keep `cluster_id, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, etc` and just put `NULL` in the columns that aren't in the set of highest values?

Comment: mathguy- I meant i've clustered the zscores for each record so thats around 2000 records with 80 variables which after clustering comes down to 19 clusters and 80 variables. What i'm trying to do is get the  top 20 variables which have the highest numbers for each cluster

Answer (score 2):

If you want the top three values, I would unpivot the data and reaggregate.  Oracle 12c has some useful functionality for this; for earlier versions I would just use more traditional SQL methods.

It is unclear whether you want the column names or the values.  The following does both:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then v end) as v_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then v end) as v_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then v end) as v_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then which end) as which_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then which end) as which_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then which end) as which_3
from (select id, v, which, row_number() over (partition by id order by v desc) as seqnum
      from ((select id, v1 as v, 'v1' as which from t) union all
            (select id, v2 as v, 'v2' as which from t) union all
            (select id, v3 as v, 'v3' as which from t) union all
            (select id, v4 as v, 'v4' as which from t) union all
            (select id, v5 as v, 'v5' as which from t)
           ) t
      ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: I would also suggest to the OP the possibility of keeping the results from the sub-query without repivotting them.  Just a kind of EAV table with `cluster_id, rank, column_identifier, value`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the approach I took was to go through all the Oracle Data Miner tables created during the clustering of my dataset. One of them , table  DM$PTCLUS_K_M_1_2 , contained a pivot table with with all the clusters,values,variable Id and name. Recreated here using my example

```
cluster_id,variable_id,value,variable_name
   1      |  1        | 4.2 | v1
```

And by doing a nested select statement with a where clause (cluster_id)  and ordering by value I could then pick out the top 10 variables and their values  for each cluster

```
select * from 
 (select * from DM$PTCLUS_K_M_1_2
     where cluster_id = 1
     order by value)
  where rownum < 11
```

For those with a similar problem and want to get cluster centroids or values i suggest looking at the dataminer schema and checking the tables there , a few of them will contain the data u need